# Cloud build error - pull access denied for python3

Tags: google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have set a trigger on Github repo using GCP cloud build.
I get error `Error response from daemon: pull access denied for python3, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied` when deploying.

Following is my cloudbuild.yaml

```
steps:
  - name: 'python:3.8'
    entrypoint: python3
    args: [ './manage.py','migrate' ]

  - name: 'python:3.8'
    entrypoint: python3
    args: [ './manage.py','collectstatic','--no input' ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: [ '-c', 'gsutil rsync -R static/ gs://xyz/static' ]

  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: [ '-c', 'gcloud config set project project1 && gcloud app deploy' ]
```

Comment: I tried to build with python:3.8, and I am able to build it successfully. I am not getting any error. So I would like to ask you that, from where are you running the builds? And have you enabled cloud build API? Please provide some more information so that we can help you.